# PHP Regular Expression Text URL to HTML Link

Tags: php, regex, url, preg-replace

I'm working on a project where I need to replace text urls anywhere from `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` to `http(s)://www.domain.com` and e-mail addresses to the proper html `<a>` tag. I was using a great solution in the past, but it used the now depreciated `eregi_replace` function. On top of that, the regular expression used for such function does not work with `preg_replace`.

So basically, the user inputs a message in which may/may not contain a link/e-mail address and I need a regular expression that works with `preg_replace` to replace that link/email with a HTML link like `<a href="link">link</a>`.

Please note that I have multiple other preg_replaces too. Below is my current code for the **other** replacements being made.

```
$patterns = array('~\[@([^\]]*)\]~','~\[([^\]]*)\]~','~{([^}]*)}~','~_([^_]*)_~','/\s{2}/');
$replacements = array('<b class="reply">@\\1</b>','<b>\\1</b>','<i>\\1</i>','<u>\\1</u>','<br />');
$msg = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $msg);
return stripslashes(utf8_encode($msg));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created a *very basic* set of Regular Expressions for this. Don't expect them to be 100% reliable, and you may need to tweak them as you go.

```
$pattern = array(
  '/((?:[\w\d]+\:\/\/)?(?:[\w\-\d]+\.)+[\w\-\d]+(?:\/[\w\-\d]+)*(?:\/|\.[\w\-\d]+)?(?:\?[\w\-\d]+\=[\w\-\d]+\&?)?(?:\#[\w\-\d]*)?)/' , # URL
  '/([\w\-\d]+\@[\w\-\d]+\.[\w\-\d]+)/' , # Email
  '/\[@([^\]]*)\]/' , # Reply
  '/\[([^\]]*)\]/' , # Bold
  '/\{([^}]*)\}/' , # Italics 
  '/_([^_]*)_/' , # Underline
  '/\s{2}/' , # Linebreak
);
$replace = array(
  '<a href="$1">$1</a>' ,
  '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>' ,
  '<b class="reply">@$1</b>' ,
  '<b>$1</b>' ,
  '<i>$1</i>' ,
  '<u>$1</u>' ,
  '<br />'
);
$msg = preg_replace( $pattern , $replace , $msg );
return stripslashes( utf8_encode( $msg ) );
```

Comment: Excellent man! You know what you are doing! I appreciate your help with this one.

Comment: quick note - add a semicolon after the closing ) for $replace.

Comment: @Lucanos this is great, but the url one, doesn't support parenthesis.