# php - find link to image in text and convert to link

Tags: php, image, hyperlink

I would like to implement the following feature onto my site. When a user posts something, he is also allowed to include one link, which is a link to a picture. Imagine a user posts something like this:

```
Hello look at this awesome picture. It is hilarious isn't it?
http://www.google.com/image.jpg
```

Then that text should be converted to:

```
Hello look at this awesome picture. It is hilarious isn't it?
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/image.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.google.com/image.jpg" alt=""/>
</a>
```

So I need some php script that searches through the text for links and if it finds a link, checks that it links to a picture. It also needs to be able to recognize links that do not start with http, and also links that start with https.

How would you do that?

Thanks a lot :)

Dennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about these two links combined:

[best way to determine if a URL is an image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676949/best-way-to-determine-if-a-url-is-an-image-in-php)

[PHP Regular Expression Text URL to HTML Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982483/php-regular-expression-text-url-to-html-link)

```
$url="http://google.com/image.jpg";

function isImage( $url ){
  $pos = strrpos( $url, ".");
    if ($pos === false)
      return false;
    $ext = strtolower(trim(substr( $url, $pos)));
    $imgExts = array(".gif", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".tiff", ".tif"); // this is far from complete but that's always going to be the case...
    if ( in_array($ext, $imgExts) )
      return true;
return false;
}

$test=isImage($url);
if($test){
  $pattern = '/((?:[\w\d]+\:\/\/)?(?:[\w\-\d]+\.)+[\w\-\d]+(?:\/[\w\-\d]+)*(?:\/|\.[\w\-\d]+)?(?:\?[\w\-\d]+\=[\w\-\d]+\&?)?(?:\#[\w\-\d]*)?)/';
  $replace = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';
  $msg = preg_replace( $pattern , $replace , $msg );
  return stripslashes( utf8_encode( $msg ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code for this:

```
<?php

$sad222="somthing text bla bla bla ...... Https://cdn.fileinfo.com/img/ss/lg/jpg_44.JPG this is my picture.";
$d11="";$cs11 = array();$i=-1;
$sad111 = explode(" ",$sad222);
foreach ($sad111 as $sad)
{

if(strtolower(substr($sad,0,7))=="http://"||strtolower(substr($sad,0,7))=="ftps://"||strtolower(substr($sad,0,8))=="https://"||strtolower(substr($sad,0,6))=="ftp://"){
if(strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-4,4))==".jpg"||strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-4,4))==".jpe"||strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-4,4))==".jif"||strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-4,4))==".jfi"||strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-4,4))==".gif"||strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-4,4))==".png"||strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-4,4))==".bmp"||strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-4,4))==".dib"||strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-4,4))==".ico"||strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-5,5))==".jpeg"||strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-5,5))==".jfif"||strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-5,5))==".apng"||strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-5,5))==".tiff"||strtolower(substr($sad,strlen($sad)-4,4))==".tif"){
$d11="<img src='".$sad."' width='500' height='600'>";
$sad=$d11;}}$i++;
$cs11[$i]=$sad." ";
}

foreach ($cs11 as $dimz)
{  
echo $dimz;
}

?>
```

Comment: Please format your code with proper indentation. Also please annotate your code so anyone can understand what you did.